# How do I click a link in a row that meets specific conditions?

Tags: html, ruby, regex, cucumber, capybara

I wish to click a link that resides in the first table row that has some text in it.

I tried the following

```
 within(all('tr').select {|elt| elt.text == "desired text" }.first) do
    all('a').first.click
 end
```

Unfortunately it didn't meet a true condition and the code was never executed. I'm probably needing a "like" command or partial text search.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you show an example of html code you expect this to match?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your link a unique css class e.g. "foobar" and use the following to click it directly:

```
page.find(:css, ".foobar").click
```

or try this to search the row with a text 'foobar' and click the link in that row with the text 'desired text' in it:

```
page.find(:xpath, "//tr[contains(.,'foobar')]/td/a", :text => 'desired text').click
```